# Clickonce Full Trust Application on Debug Mode

Tags: wpf, clickonce, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an error publishing my clickonce app.
When a publish it in Debug mode, it works fine, but, if I publish it with Release mode and security exception is thrown.
Diggin in, I've found a difference between the manifests.
The working manifest haver this:

```
<applicationRequestMinimum>
    <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
  </applicationRequestMinimum>
```

And the manifest published in Release mode have this:

```
<applicationRequestMinimum>
    <PermissionSet version="1" class="System.Security.NamedPermissionSet" Name="LocalIntranet" Description="Default rights given to applications on the local intranet" ID="Custom" SameSite="site">
      <IPermission Read="USERNAME" version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.FileDialogPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
      <IPermission version="1" Permanent="True" Expiry="9223372036854775807" UserQuota="9223372036854775807" Allowed="AssemblyIsolationByUser" class="System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Flags="ReflectionEmit, RestrictedMemberAccess" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Flags="Assertion, Execution, BindingRedirects" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Level="DefaultPrinting" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.MediaPermission, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Audio="SafeAudio" Image="SafeImage" Video="SafeVideo" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.WebBrowserPermission, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Level="Safe" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Net.DnsPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
      <IPermission version="1" class="System.Security.Permissions.TypeDescriptorPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Unrestricted="true" />
    </PermissionSet>
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
  </applicationRequestMinimum>
```

I've found this issue because I try to use VSTS Build Task and when I publish using msbuild commandline, this use Release Mode.

How can I force to generate the first type of manifest?

Edit: This is de .csproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{2B3F0BA0-0F55-4F3D-ADD4-5D5E0A19C85C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WinSPC.Stratifications.View</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WinSPC.Stratifications</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Unc</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <InstallUrl>\\JAL01WINSPC\WinSPCRemote\Modulos\StratificationBotes\</InstallUrl>
    <ProductName>WinSPC.Estratificación</ProductName>
    <PublisherName>CdelIT</PublisherName>
    <SuiteName>WinSPC.Estratificación</SuiteName>
    <CreateWebPageOnPublish>true</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
    <WebPage>index.htm</WebPage>
    <ApplicationRevision>26</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>2.6.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>2</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>8EB250AABD2F38D9886B31E0FC3C06190BAC6D2A</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestKeyFile>View_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>logo.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetZone>Custom</TargetZone>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight, Version=5.3.0.19026, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7570ab207bcb616, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.3.0.0\lib\net45\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras, Version=5.3.0.19032, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669f0b5e8f868abf, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.3.0.0\lib\net45\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform, Version=5.3.0.19032, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5f873c45e98af8a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.3.0.0\lib\net45\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MahApps.Metro, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4fb5a3c4d1e5b4f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MahApps.Metro.1.4.1\lib\net45\MahApps.Metro.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.3\lib\portable-net4+sl5+netcore45+wpa81+wp8\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MoreLinq, Version=2.0.20029.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=384d532d7e88985d, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\morelinq.2.0.0\lib\net35\MoreLinq.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="OxyPlot, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=638079a8f0bd61e9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\OxyPlot.Core.1.0.0\lib\net45\OxyPlot.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="OxyPlot.Wpf, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=75e952ba404cdbb0, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\OxyPlot.Wpf.1.0.0\lib\net45\OxyPlot.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MahApps.Metro.1.4.1\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Compile Include="ExtendedControls\ExtendedTreeView.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ExtendedControls\TextBoxHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\ControlsWrapper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\ErrorHandler.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\InputWrapper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\InvertBoolConverter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\StratificationControlWrapper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\TagControlWrapper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\ViewModelLocator.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\BoxPlotViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\DataCollectionViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\DataCollectionBoxPlotViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\BoxPlot.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>BoxPlot.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\DataCollection.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DataCollection.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\DataCollectionBoxPlot.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DataCollectionBoxPlot.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\SetStratification.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SetStratification.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Page Include="Views\BoxPlot.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\CollectionPlanSelection.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\DataCollection.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\DataCollectionBoxPlot.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\Login.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\Main.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Helpers\MessageBoxService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\NavigateMessage.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\StratificationItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Helpers\ShuttingDownMessage.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IMessageBoxService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IView.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\CollectionPlanSelectionViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\LoginViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\SetStratificationViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\CollectionPlanSelection.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CollectionPlanSelection.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\Login.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Login.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\Main.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Main.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Page Include="Views\SetStratification.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="App.Release.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <AppDesigner Include="Properties\" />
    <None Include="Tools\BuildScripts\version.ps1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Exceptions\Exceptions.csproj">
      <Project>{062B62A0-1C97-4662-9263-5AF3EFDC83BD}</Project>
      <Name>Exceptions</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Extensions\Extensions.csproj">
      <Project>{ECECE8C5-BFBC-4A05-9832-DD7FAFC75632}</Project>
      <Name>Extensions</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Helpers\Helpers.csproj">
      <Project>{63DDEE64-811D-4666-AF53-237498743DF8}</Project>
      <Name>Helpers</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Model\Model.csproj">
      <Project>{9D8E5FA6-89A8-4453-AAD2-6833CD0030FB}</Project>
      <Name>Model</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Services\Services.csproj">
      <Project>{FDFB442F-BF97-4BB1-84D4-433A1D1BFBD3}</Project>
      <Name>Services</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\error.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\success.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\round-play-button.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\pocket_error.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\pocket_success.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\logo.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\exit.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\pocket.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\refresh.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\return-arrow.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\folder.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\collectionplan.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\back.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\logo.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="logo.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\logoEnvases.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\warning.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\select.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\unchecked.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Tools\BuildScripts\mage.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

/target:publish /p:ApplicationVersion=$(ApplicationVersion) /p:UpdateEnabled=true /p:UpdateMode=Foreground  /p:InstallUrl=$(URL) /p:InstallFrom=Unc /p:ProductName=WinSPC.Estratificación /p:BootstrapperEnabled=true

Update:
In my Build Definition I have a transform task, I use this for ConnectionString update.
If I disable this  task, the published app works fine, but with this task (before build) enabled, the published app throw the security exception.
Any ideas?

Comment: It is based on the value of unrestricted (Properties > app.manifest or right click the project > Properties > Security), if true, the permission grant is unconditional. If false, or if this attribute is undefined, it is restricted according to the permission-specific attributes defined on the IPermission tag. Do you specify manifest file (app.manifest by default) when publish? Provide the detail steps and configuration of your build definition, also please provide the detail code of your project file (csproj).

Comment: I've edited the post with the information.

Comment: Which transform task you used? What's the detail errors of security exception? Can you reproduce that issue with a new project? If so, can you share it on the OneDrive?